# Flink statsD metric

Tags: java, apache-flink, statsd

i am not able to see statistic that sent from flink to statsd. Already placed flink-metrics-statsd-1.4.1.jar in JM and TMs /lib folder.
With the code below, I would expect to see "myCounter" as a influxDB series. But there is nothing in the influxDB, so nothing show inGrafana. Any advice? thanks!

```java
public class StatsdCounter extends RichMapFunction<String, String> {
    private transient Counter counter;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        this.counter = getRuntimeContext()
        .getMetricGroup()
        .counter("myCounter");
    }

    @Override
    public String map(String value) throws Exception {
        this.counter.inc();
        return value;
}
```

in flink-conf.yaml,

```
metrics.scope.jm: <host>.jobmanager
metrics.scope.jm.job: <host>.jobmanager.<job_name>
metrics.scope.tm: <host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>
metrics.scope.tm.job: <host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>.<job_name>
metrics.scope.task: <host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>.<job_name>.<task_name>.<subtask_index>
metrics.scope.operator: <host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>.<job_name>.<operator_name>.<subtask_index>

metrics.reporters: stsd
metrics.reporter.stsd.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.statsd.StatsDReporter
metrics.reporter.stsd.host: 192.168.56.10
metrics.reporter.stsd.port: 8127
metrics.reporter.stsd.interval: 1 SECONDS
```

But it will work if we set the statsd manually in the code,

```java
public void open(Configuration configuration) throws Exception {
    super.open(configuration);
    counter = new AtomicInteger(); 
    stats = new NonBlockingStatsDClient(xxx);
}

@Override
public String map(String value) throws Exception { 
  stats.increment(statsdAspect); 
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Don't see anything obvious. Are you sure 8127 is the right port? The default is 8125. Have you checked the logs for errors? Maybe check the statsd and influx logs too (I assume you've setup influxdb as the backend for statsd).

Comment: the port is correct as we are able to send statsd record by calling NonBlockingStatsDClient(xxx) using the same port. No error in flink node, all statsd lib and config loaded successfully. No error in telegraf log too :(

I managed to see the new counter by using JMX reporter too so the code seems ok. Any clue again? thanks

Comment: Maybe I can see the problem - do you run flink jobs on multiple machines?

Comment: @GeorgiStoyanov yes with 4 task manager, any tips?

Comment: I had similar issue - my machines couldn't see the machine with the running statsd (I change the IP to the real one and everything worked) Hope this is your case :/

Comment: @GeorgiStoyanov which IP you meant?

Comment: @user3771883 of the host, but again - this was my case :)